# gamma function with negative argument

Tags: asymptotics, gamma-function

For $k=0,1,2...$ and small $z$ I want to show that $$\Gamma (-k + z) = \frac{ a_k}{z} + b_k + O(z).$$ I understand that the gamma function cannot be expressed as   $$\Gamma ( z) = \int_0 ^\infty e^{-x} x^{z-1} dx$$ for negative values of $z$. The graph below shows that for $z \in \mathbb{z^-}$ the function is alternating between positive and negative infinity thus the need for the small value to be included.
[Graph of \Gamma(z)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JagXH.png)

Comment: Do you know about Euler's reflection equation: $\Gamma(z)\Gamma(1-z)\sin\pi z = \pi$? That may help.

Comment: That, or the recurrence relation $\Gamma(z+1)=z\Gamma(z)$

Comment: So how would the recurrence relation relate to this? I understand that it yields the result $\Gamma(n) = (n-1)!$ but only for positive values of z.

Answer (score 2):

> $a_k~=~\lim\limits_{z\to0}~z~\Gamma(z-k)~=~\dfrac{(-1)^k}{k!}$
>
> $b_k~=~\lim\limits_{z\to0}~\Gamma(z-k)-\dfrac{a_k}z~=~-\dfrac{(-1)^k}{k!}\cdot\gamma~-~\dfrac{S_1(k+1,~2)}{k!^2}$

See [Euler-Mascheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler-Mascheroni_constant) and [Stirling numbers of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind) for more information.