# solution of $\int_0^{\infty}x^{-n}e^{-ax}$

Tags: integration

How do I evaluate the following integral,

$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{-n}e^{-ax}
$$

**Note:** I don't think i can apply $\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{n}e^{-ax}=\frac{n!}{a^{n+1}}$

Comment: If $n>0$ the integrand has a singularity at zero...

Comment: your integral is convergent iff $n < 1$ and $a > 0$

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1553847/gamma-function-with-negative-argument

Comment: @user1952009  n >0 and a>0

Comment: @ss1729 : $\int_0^b x^{-n} dx$ is divergent whenever $n \ge 1$, and since $e^{-ax} \sim 1$ when $x \to 0$, $\int_0^b x^{-n} e^{-ax} dx$ is divergent too. are you sure you understand the Riemann integral ? it is defined at first only when integrating a continuous function on $[c,d]$. then, we also consider more general cases by letting $c$ or $d$ tend to $\infty$ or a singularity point of the integrand

Answer (score 0):

For small $x$, the exponential factor is about $1$. Then

$$\int_0^\epsilon x^{-n}dx=\left.\frac{x^{1-n}}{1-n}\right|_0^\epsilon.$$

Do you see the problem ?

Comment: your explication is weird. if $n > 1$ : $\int_0^1 x^{-n} dx = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \int_\epsilon^1 x^{-n} dx =  \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+}  \frac{1-\epsilon^{1-n}}{1-n} = \infty$

Comment: @user1952009: nope, my $\epsilon$ is a finite value (your $1$). I want to stress that... "there is a problem".

Comment: you are wrong. if $f(x)$ is singular at $x= 0$ and continuous on $]0,1]$, then by definition $\displaystyle \int_0^1 f(x) dx \overset{def}{=} \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \int_\epsilon^1 f(x) dx$ ...

Comment: @user1952009: what's wrong saying that there is a problem ? I don't think you see my point and keep focused on that limit.

Comment: I'm saying that writing "if $f$ was continuous on $[0,1]$, then we would obtain $0^{1-n}$ which is undefined since $1-n < 0$, hence contradicting that $f$ is continuous on $[0,1]$" is not an adapted answer...

Comment: and I keep focused on a limit : of course, since what we are considering is a limit

Comment: @user1952009: for the last time, I am not saying that what I wrote is a valid answer. I am drawing the attention of the OP on an anomaly. Try to understand my point, not yours.

Comment: you don't understand that this proves nothing, not even that there is a problem. would you write that $\int_0^1 \ln x dx = \left. x \ln x + 1 \right|_0^1$ ?

Comment: ok, so you have to agree that you have to enhance the $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+}$, that's the only way to explain what is happening