# Calculate limit of $\Gamma$ function for special values.

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence, gamma-function

I would like to calculate the limit without any software but have no idea how to do it.

$$f(n) = \lim_{c \rightarrow 0} \frac{\Gamma(-n + c) + \Gamma(-n - c))}{2}$$
$$n = 0, 1, 2, ...$$

Wolfram in some way claculates it, for example:
$$f(0) = - \gamma$$
$$f(1) = \gamma - 1$$
$$f(2) = \frac{3 - 2 \gamma}{4}$$
$$f(3) = \frac{6 \gamma - 11}{36}$$
$$(...)$$

It seems that the solutions will be somethink like that:
$$f(n) = \frac{(a - \gamma)(-1)^{n}}{b}$$

Comment: $Gamma$ has poles at the nonpositive integers, and you are finding the residues at those poles.  This is the terminology you will use to find it in the literature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [series expansions](https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/Gamma/06/01/05/01/0002/) for the gamma function we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
f(n)
&=\frac{1}{2}\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}(\Gamma(-n+\epsilon)+\Gamma(-n-\epsilon))\\
&=\frac{(-1)^n}{2 n!}\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}(\tfrac{1}{\epsilon}(1+\psi(n+1)\epsilon)-\tfrac{1}{\epsilon}(1-\psi(n+1)\epsilon)+\mathcal O(\epsilon))\\
&=\frac{(-1)^n}{2 n!}\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}(\tfrac{1}{\epsilon}+\psi(n+1)-\tfrac{1}{\epsilon}+\psi(n+1)+\mathcal O(\epsilon))\\
&=\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}(\psi(n+1)+\mathcal O(\epsilon))\\
&=\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\psi(n+1),
\end{aligned}
$$
where $\psi(z)$ is the [Digamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function). Then using [specialized values](http://functions.wolfram.com/06.14.03.0001.01) for $\psi(n+1)$ we find
$$
\begin{aligned}
f(n)
&=\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}(H_n-\gamma),
\end{aligned}
$$
where $H_n$ is the [harmonic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#:%7E:text=Harmonic%20numbers%20are%20related%20to,various%20branches%20of%20number%20theory.) and $\gamma=0.57721\dots$ is the [Euler-Mascheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant).

We have for the first several values of $n$:
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & f(n)\\
 0 & -\gamma  \\
 1 & \gamma-1 \\
 2 & -\frac{1}{2} \left(\gamma-\frac{3}{2} \right) \\
 3 & \frac{1}{6} \left(\gamma -\frac{11}{6}\right) \\
 4 & -\frac{1}{24} \left(\gamma-\frac{25}{12} \right) \\
 5 & \frac{1}{120} \left(\gamma -\frac{137}{60}\right) \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way to do it. Using the [reflection formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#General) for the gamma function write
$$
\begin{aligned}
f(n)
&=\frac{1}{2}\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}(\Gamma(-n+\epsilon)+\Gamma(-n-\epsilon))\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2}\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\left(\frac{1}{\Gamma(1+n-\epsilon)\sin\pi(-n+\epsilon)}+\frac{1}{\Gamma(1+n+\epsilon)\sin\pi(-n-\epsilon)}\right)\\
&=\frac{(-1)^n\pi}{2}\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\left(\frac{1}{\Gamma(1+n-\epsilon)\sin\pi\epsilon}-\frac{1}{\Gamma(1+n+\epsilon)\sin\pi\epsilon}\right)\\
&=\frac{(-1)^n\pi}{2\Gamma(1+n)^2}\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\left(\frac{\Gamma(1+n+\epsilon)-\Gamma(1+n-\epsilon)}{\underbrace{\sin\pi\epsilon}_{\sim\pi\epsilon}}\right)\\
&=\frac{(-1)^n}{2(n!)^2}\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\left(\frac{\Gamma(1+n+\epsilon)-\Gamma(1+n-\epsilon)}{\epsilon}\right),\quad^\ast\text{L'Hôpital}\\
&=\frac{(-1)^n}{2(n!)^2}\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\left(\psi(1+n+\epsilon)\Gamma(1+n+\epsilon)+\psi(1+n-\epsilon)\Gamma(1+n-\epsilon)\right)\\
&=\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\psi(n+1).
\end{aligned}
$$
Then again use the specialized values for $\psi(n+1)$.

Answer (score 0):

Using results from [gamma function with negative argument](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1553847/450342)

$$\Gamma (-n + c) = \frac{ a_n}{c} + b_n + O(c)$$

with
$$b_n~=~-\dfrac{(-1)^n}{n!}\cdot\gamma~-~\dfrac{S_1(n+1,~2)}{n!^2}$$

thus your limit is
$$
f(n)=\lim_{c\rightarrow 0}\frac{\Gamma (-n + c) + \Gamma (-n - c)}{2}= b_n
$$

For $n=0, 2, \dots, 5$:

$$
\begin{array}{l}
 f(0) =  -\gamma  \\
f(1) = -1+\gamma  \\
f(2) = \frac{3}{4}-\frac{\gamma }{2} \\
f(3) = -\frac{11}{36}+\frac{\gamma }{6} \\
f(4) = \frac{25}{288}-\frac{\gamma }{24} \\
f(5) = -\frac{137}{7200}+\frac{\gamma }{120} \\
\end{array}
$$